# WooCommerce order note color

Tags: css, woocommerce-offtopic

Is it possible to give different color for different order notes blocks in order detail page?

For example;

- `green` for "Order status changed from Processing to Completed."
- `blue` for "Order status changed from Pending Payment to Processing."
- etc. ...

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce 2.5 is on its way. That introduces a filter for $note_classes which was missing in previous version. Once that ships, you can use following code which adds css classes to order note containers. Then you can use those classes to apply colors. You need to put this in your functions.php file.

```
function woo_process_order_note_classes($note_classes, $note){

    $per_note_status = explode('to ', $note->comment_content );

    switch ($per_note_status[1]) {
        case 'Pending Payment.':
            $note_classes[] = 'pending-note';
            return $note_classes;
            break;

        case 'Processing.':
            $note_classes[] = 'processing-note';
            return $note_classes;
            break;

        case 'On Hold.':
            $note_classes[] = 'onhold-note';
            return $note_classes;
            break;

        case 'Completed.':
            $note_classes[] = 'completed-note';
            return $note_classes;
            break;

        case 'Cancelled.':
            $note_classes[] = 'cancelled-note';
            return $note_classes;
            break;

        case 'Refunded.':
            $note_classes[] = 'refunded-note';
            return $note_classes;
            break;

        case 'Failed.':
            $note_classes[] = 'failed-note';
            return $note_classes;
            break;

        default:
            return get_comment_meta( $note->comment_ID, 'is_customer_note', true ) ? array( 'customer-note', 'note' ) : array( 'note' );
            break;
    }

}
add_filter('woocommerce_order_note_class', 'woo_process_order_note_classes', 10, 2);
```

Also don't forget to create order-note.css file. Below is css which I used:

```
.note.pending-note .note_content { background: #993300; color: #ffffff; }
    .note.pending-note .note_content:after { border-color: #993300 transparent; }

.note.processing-note .note_content { background: #00FF00; color: #000000; }
    .note.processing-note .note_content:after { border-color: #00FF00 transparent; }

.note.onhold-note .note_content { background: gray; color: #ffffff;}
    .note.onhold-note .note_content:after { border-color: gray transparent; }

.note.completed-note .note_content { background: #003300; color: #ffffff; }
    .note.completed-note .note_content:after { border-color: #003300 transparent; }

.note.cancelled-note .note_content { background: #280000 ; color: #ffffff; }
    .note.cancelled-note .note_content:after { border-color: #280000 transparent; }

.note.refunded-note .note_content { background: #0066FF; color: #ffffff; }
    .note.refunded-note .note_content:after { border-color: #0066FF transparent; }

.note.failed-note .note_content { background: #CC0000; color: #ffffff; }
    .note.failed-note .note_content:after { border-color: #CC0000 transparent; }
```

Comment: I have created a small plugin which will help those who don't want to go into codes. The plugin is available in [WordPress plugin repo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/colored-order-notes-for-woocommerce/).